# How to merger these two records ino one row removing Null value in Informatica using transformation. Please see the snapshot for scenario

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTej2.png)

Input-

```
Code value Min Max

A   abc   10   null
A   abc   Null 20
```

Output-

```
Code value Min Max

A    abc  10 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregator transformation to remove nulls and get single row. I am providing solution based on your data only.
use an aggregator with below ports -

```
inout_Code  (group by)
inout_value (group by)
in_Min 
in_Max
out_Min= MAX(in_Min)
out_Max = MAX(in_Max)
```

And then attach out_Min, out_Max, code and value to target.
You will get 1 record for a combination of code and value and null values will be gone.

Now, if you have more than 4/5/6/more etc. code,value combinations and some of min, max columns are null and you want multiple records, you need more complex mapping logic. Let me know if this helps. :)